# GET is outdated?

Tags: php, path, get, directory

I was told that using $_GET to fetch content is old school and should use folder path instead for seo purpose.

example

GET

```
http://domain.com/content.php?id=1
```

Folder Path

```
http://domain.com/content/this-is-an-article
```

How true is this and which 1 should I use?

Comment: I think you are mixing different things here. Using $_GET surely isn't outdated, but what you are looking for is what @caCtus commented. Have a look at the question he posted

Comment: Is it not more about RESTful APIs?

Comment: This is a bad mix :)

Answer (score 0):

Both.

Using folder style URLs is better for SEO however behind the scenes these are normally rewritten (using rewrite rules in .htaccess if using apache) to convert them to the appropriate get url.

So

```
http://domain.com/content/this-is-an-article
```

would get rewritten behind the scenes to

```
http://domain.com/content.php?title=this-is-an-article
```

To users of your website they see/use the folder version of the URL.

An example apache rewrite rule for this would be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^content/([^/\.]+)/?$ content.php?title=$1 [L]
```